# IE8: making the `nth-child` selector work inside media queries?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

In my website projects, i use **media queries** and the **nth-child selector**.

IE8 doesn't support them out of the box, but there are polyfills to help:

- [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), [mediatizr](https://github.com/pyrsmk/mediatizr) or [css3-mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) enable media queries in IE8;
- [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) or [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) enable the nth-child selector.

My problem is that i need to use **nth-child inside media queries**. A synthetic example:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .foo:nth-child(2n) {
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

I need this code to work in IE8.

The problem is that neither selectivizr, nor ie9.js parse `nth-child` inside media queries, and media query-enabling polyfills won't help because they interfere with the `nth-child` polyfills when used together.

Please suggest a way to make that code work in IE8!

Comment: What do you mean by "[media query-enabling polyfills] work independently"?

Comment: @BoltClock http://am-teh.ru

Comment: @Shauna This means they don't work together. There have been efforts on combining Respond+mediatizr, and some devs have even got positive results, but that efforts didn't reach production. :( For instance, here's a year old thread: https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/issues/23

Comment: Here's another effort of making Respond and mediatizr work together: http://selectivizr.com/tests/respond/ Unfortunately, it's not production ready too. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have to use media queries on IE8 ? Is it for large screen layouts ? I always tell my QA team / and coworkers that any site tested on desktop should not be QA'ed for any size smaller than the main grid ( 960px - 1000px usually ). I find a waste of time and resources making a site work on IE at anything smaller than such sizes. 
It comes back to when we didnt have responsive design a few years ago. We wouldnt test for smaller screens back then, and there is still no reason to test that now ( on desktops ).

Comment: @PabloRincon I develop responsive styles only for modern browsers. They display completely distorted in IE 7-8. Now i have two options: 1. Develop a separate set of styles specifically for IE 7-8. It takes days/weeks of work to increase browser coverage for only 1.5% and the result is not responsive. 2. Throw in the polyfill. It takes like 15 minutes and the result is automatically responsive in IE. The 2nd option has [some drawbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720043/how-do-you-use-mobile-first-with-in-ie8#comment32782682_16732064) though, so use it only when your budget is limited.

Comment: Also, the idea of [modern web design](http://futurefriend.ly) is to make your website automatically adapt to capabilities of various devices (feature detection, progressive enhancement and shit) without classifying device into groups like "mobile/tablet/desktop" and adapting your website to those distinct groups. The diversity of devices is ever growing, and the device segregation approach is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, i figured it out.

Selectivizr and Respond have both been modified to work together ([1](https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/issues/23), [2](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/36)).

The matter is that necessary changes have been commited to Selectivizr version 1.0.3b. As of March 2013, 1.0.3b has not been released. It is neither available on Selectivizr's official website, nor in CDNs. It can only be [obtained](https://raw.github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/master/selectivizr.js) from project's repo and only the uncompressed edition is available for now.

Respond is more prompt with releases, so the latest official version will do.

Note that Selectivizr should be included first, Respond second. And don't forget to include one of [Selectivizr's requirements](http://selectivizr.com/#how) before Selectivizr! So the correct order is:

1. NWMatcher (or alternative)
2. Selectivizr
3. Respond

And don't use [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)! It has it's own implementation of media queries and together with Respond will render your site unusable in IE < 9.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work in IE8 because [IE8 doesn't support media queries at all](http://caniuse.com/#search=media). If you want media queries in IE8, then you need to find a polyfill that enables that.

You should be able to achieve what you want with a combination of the media query and selector polyfills, which you can use on the same page, because they are generally written so as to not interfere with each other.

**Edit** If the polyfills really don't work with each other, then I'd take a serious look as to why you think you need media query support for IE8. Chances are, you'd be just fine, with a few tweaks, just letting IE8 do its own thing. It's very likely that IE8 users aren't going to be on very large or very small screens, due to the combination of IE8 only being on Windows XP and some Windows Vista machines (Win7 ships with IE9), and Windows Phone having very small market share in the mobile arena. Chance are, you're putting in a lot of effort for next to no return.

However, if you do find that you *need* media query type support for IE8 for whatever reason, then I'd look into a more basic JavaScript option that just detects the window size and applies a class accordingly (this should be pretty straighforward even in vanilla JS, but most of the libraries make this even more trivial). You can wrap the JavaScript reference in a conditional comment to sandbox it from every other browser.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the question - it seems the OP has been unable to get a combination of both polyfills working together.

Comment: All Modernizr does is provide information on whether a browser supports media queries and `:nth-child()` use - it doesn't polyfill anything.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's not really how I took the "they won't help because they work independently" line to mean. That line suggested to me that the OP doesn't understand that you can, in fact, leverage two different polyfills at the same time (provided they are intelligent enough to namespace themselves).

Comment: @BoltClock re Modernizr - Fair enough. As I said, I haven't used it myself. It does, however, provide a link to a nice list of polyfills that might prove useful (including several others for Media Queries) - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @BoltClock Why did you mention Modernizr in the first place?

Comment: @lolmaus - I had originally suggested it, but have since edited it out.

Comment: @Shauna Of course i had tried all combinations of querying and selecting polyfills prior to asking. No combination works. Also, i had studied their issue queues and found efforts on combining Respond with mediatizr. There are success reports from coders but no working solution released that i coulld find.

Answer (score 1):

Am also stuck with the same issue at the moment and am busy playing around with a couple ideas to try and make this work.

One *hack* that seems to be working is to pull all the functions in selectivizr.js out to a global level (requires the variables to be declared globally too). Then, you can change css-mediaqueries to call patchStyleSheet with the contents of the media query before adding it to the styles (line 916 of [the following version of css-mediaqueries.js](https://github.com/livingston/css3-mediaqueries-js)):

```
styles[styles.length] = cssHelper.addStyle('@media ' + s.join('') + '{' + patchStyleSheet(mql.getCssText()) + '}', false);
```

So, I'm not saying this is an ideal solution - declaring all the functions and variables in selectivizr at a global level is obviously not the best idea - but, it does seem to work and proves it's possible. With a bit more time one could probably combine the 2 scripts into a much better solution.